# SimpleDateFormat giving NullPointerException, no matter which pattern I pass through

Tags: java, android-studio

When I run my code the function InternetTime returns the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1035)
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:577)
```

My code looks like this,

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "H:mm dd/MM/yyyy";

public InternetTime(String dateString){
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        assert date != null;
        cal.setTime(date);
        // Initializing
        year = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("yyyy", cal).toString());
        month = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("MM", cal).toString());
        day = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("dd", cal).toString());
        hour = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("H", cal).toString());
        minute = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("mm", cal).toString());
        mDate = date;
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I receive the following dateString from a server: "time": "13:07 08/01/2021"

Comment: You are passing in a null `dateString` in the constructor

Comment: The error details, that you posted in your question, indicate that `dateString`, i.e. the parameter to method `InternetTime`, is null. I'm guessing that you are receiving a JSON string from the server. Are you sure that you are parsing the JSON correctly? Are you sure of the value being passed to method `InternetTime`?

Comment: @AlBlue, the date string I'm getting is fetched from a server using an API, 

String dateToFormat = response.body().getTime();

then

 restaurantUtils = new RestaurantUtils(dateToFormat);

then

public RestaurantUtils(String dateString){
        InternetTime internetTime = new InternetTime(dateString);

then

InternetTime is executed.

Comment: So you need to verify that it's not null before passing it into this method/constructor -- or better yet, use an `Objects.requireNotNull` to make sure you're validating input. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)

Comment: @Abra I think I am parsing it correctly, because this is how I fetch it: String dateToFormat = response.body().getTime(); then I pass it  through a function restaurantUtils = new RestaurantUtils(dateToFormat).

public RestaurantUtils(String dateString){
      InternetTime internetTime = new InternetTime(dateString)
}

InternetTime is what I posted in the question initially.

Comment: Method `parse(String, ParsePosition)`, in class `SimpleDateFormat` is throwing `NullPointerException` because the `String` parameter is null. That's a fact. So it doesn't matter what you _think_. Check the value of the parameter you are passing to your invocation of method `parse` to verify that it is **not** null. Do you not know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I do. Let me do that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Abra it's returning a null, you were right. Turns out my problem is with the API response. Retrofit is returning "c.f.a.r0@13b62af9" instead of a json